# Append JSON array to an object

Tags: postgresql, functions, json

I'm trying to transform a table that has a rows with the some attributes that are the same, but others that differ like the table below to a specific JSON structure.

| id | name | language | attr1 | attr2 | attr3 | attr4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | Example 1 | en | 0 | 80 | 10 | 100 |
| 13 | Ejemplo 1 | es | 0 | 80 | 10 | 100 |
| 21 | Beispiel 2 | de | 35 | 80 | 20 | 75 |
| 21 | Exemple 2 | fr | 35 | 80 | 20 | 75 |

As some of the columns have the same value, I want them inside an object, and the columns that have different content as an array, like this:

```json
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "id": 13,
      "attr1": 0,
      "attr2": 80,
      "attr3": 10,
      "attr4": 100,
      "names": [
        {
          "language": "en",
          "name": "Example 1"
        },
        {
          "language": "es",
          "name": "Ejemplo 1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 21,
      "attr1": 35,
      "attr2": 80,
      "attr3": 20,
      "attr4": 75,
      "names": [
        {
          "language": "de",
          "name": "Beispiel 2"
        },
        {
          "language": "fr",
          "name": "Exemple 2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I made a function that generates the accounts array without the names array in every object:

```
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(accounts)) AS accounts
FROM (
         SELECT DISTINCT id, attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4
         FROM temp_table_from_fuction()
         ORDER BY attr1, attr2
     ) accounts
```

(`temp_table_from_fuction()` returns the first table)

This is the result:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 13,
    "attr1": 0,
    "attr2": 80,
    "attr3": 10,
    "attr4": 100
  },
  {
    "id": 21,
    "attr1": 35,
    "attr2": 80,
    "attr3": 20,
    "attr4": 75
  }
]
```

How can I append an array to a JSON object calling the `temp_table_from_fuction()` again? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put a PostgreSQL version tag, but there are functions added around 9.4 that will help with this: you can use `jsonb_object_agg()`, `jsonb_build_object()` and `jsonb_build_array()` (or their equivalent `json_` functions if you don't want `jsonb`).

See documentation here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-json.html

As a side note, you should normalize that table if it really is a table and not a view.  Specifically, have a look at [second normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form).